# Frac function losing precision

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, precision, floating-accuracy, tdatetime

I have a TDateTime variable which is assigned a value at runtime of 40510.416667. When I extract the time to a TTime type variable using the Frac function, it sets it to 0.41666666666. Why has it changed the precision of the value and is there a workround to retain the precision from the original value ie. to set it to 0.416667.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reason for the loss of precision is that TDateTime is a double, and Frac's parameter and return value is of type Extended.

When converting floating points from one type to another, *some* precision can be lost. (Same goes when doing arithmetic on them).

To compare float value correctly, you should use the CompareValue function from the unit Math.

Answer (score 2):

TDateTime is a floating point number. Some numbers can't be represented exactly as a floating point number. 0.416667 / 0.41666666666 would seem to be another one.

You can round to 5 or 6 digits for display. That gets you accuracy to around 1 second.

Answer (score 2):

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Numbers](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg%5Fgoldberg.html) should help, as should SO's own [Precision of Floating Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872544/precision-of-floating-point) - that will give you some detailed information to go with Jeff's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your help on this, much appreciated. To get round my problen that was arising due to the change in precision I used the CompareTime function instead of the >= or <= operators for comparing the times.