# Problem with calculating floats

Tags: iphone, objective-c

strange situation, when performing the following lines of Code:

```
const float a = 47.848711;
const float b = 47.862952;
float result = b - a;
```

I get a (NSLog %.10f) result = 0.0142440796.

I expected to get 0.0142410000.

What's going on?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872544/precision-of-floating-point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if I ask you the following:

> ```
> const int a = 1.3;
> const int b = 2.7;
> int result = b - a;
> ```
>
> I get a (NSLog %d) result = 1.
>
> I expected to get 1.4.  What's going on?

In this case, the answer is obvious, right?  1.3 isn't an integer, so the actual value that gets stored in `a` is 1, and the value that gets stored in `b` isn't 2.7, but rather 2.  When I subtract 1 from 2 I get exactly 1, which is the observed answer.  If you're with me so far, keep reading.

---

The exact same thing is happening in your example.  47.848711 isn't a single-precision float, so the closest floating-point value is stored in `a` instead, which is exactly:

```
a = 47.8487091064453125
```

Similarly, the value stored in `b` is the closest floating-point value to `47.862952`, which is exactly:

```
b = 47.86295318603515625
```

When you subtract these numbers to get `result`, you get:

```
  47.86295318603515625
- 47.8487091064453125
----------------------
   0.01424407958984375
```

When you round that value to 10 digits to print it out, you get:

```
   0.0142440796
```

Answer (score 6):

Classic!

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

(basically, floating points can be inaccurate; [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)).