# Issue with precision of Ruby math operations

Tags: ruby, math, rounding, precision

Do you know how to fix the following issue with math precision?

```
p RUBY_VERSION # => "1.9.1"
p 0.1%1 # => 0.1
p 1.1%1 # => 0.1
p 90.0%1 # => 0.0
p 90.1%1 # => 0.0999999999999943
p 900.1%1 # => 0.100000000000023

p RUBY_VERSION # => "1.9.2"
p 0.1%1 # => 0.1
p 1.1%1 # => 0.10000000000000009
p 90.0%1 # => 0.0
p 90.1%1 # => 0.09999999999999432
p 900.1%1 # => 0.10000000000002274
```

Comment: This has been asked 4000 times I guess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Precision of Floating Point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872544/precision-of-floating-point)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Big Decimal

As the [man](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) said;

> Squeezing infinitely many real numbers into a finite number of bits requires an approximate representation.

I have however had great success using the [BigDecimal](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/index.html) class. To quote its intro

> Ruby provides built-in support for arbitrary precision integer arithmetic. For example:
>
> 42**13 -> 1265437718438866624512
>
> BigDecimal provides similar support for very large or very accurate floating point numbers.

**Taking one of your examples;**

```
>> x = BigDecimal.new('900.1')
=> #<BigDecimal:101113be8,'0.9001E3',8(8)>
>> x % 1
=> #<BigDecimal:10110b498,'0.1E0',4(16)>
>> y = x % 1
=> #<BigDecimal:101104760,'0.1E0',4(16)>
>> y.to_s
=> "0.1E0"
>> y.to_f
=> 0.1
```

As you can see, ensuring decent precision is possible but it requires a little bit of effort.

Comment: Mind!  You're not just adding precision: you're choosing a better representation for decimal numbers.  1/3 will still be rounded.

Comment: @xtofl - that's a fair point but I hoped that the quote about 'approximate representation' touched on it.

Answer (score 2):

This is true of all computer languages, not just Ruby.  It's a feature of representing floating point numbers on binary computers:

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1):

Writing `0.1` into a floating point will always result in rounding errors.  If you want 'precise' decimal representation, you should use the [`Decimal` type](http://ruby-decimal.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: I haven't noticed such issue in `PHP`. Is there any good reason why Ruby doesn't have "'precise' decimal representation" by default?

Comment: PHP has the same problem, because it's not about language: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php