# decimal rounding is off for (276/304)*304

Tags: c#, .net, types, floating-point

If you put the following code in your compiler the result is a bit bizar:

```
decimal x = (276/304)*304;
double y = (276/304)*304;

Console.WriteLine("decimal x = " + x);
Console.WriteLine("double y = " + y);
```

Result:

> decimal x = 275.99999999999999999999999
>
> double y = 276.0

Can someone explain this to me? I don't understand how this can be correct.

Comment: Actually, the result of both of the first expressions is simply 0. The arithmetic on the RHS of the assignment operator is performed in the integer domain, so the bracketed expression has the value 0 in each case.

Comment: This is to be expected (given a valid expression). Not all floating point numbers can be represented exactly in binary so there will be rounding errors in calculations. You will get different rounding errors for `decimal` and `double` as their bit representations are different. This is also a duplicate question.

Comment: It is correct.  Search SO for the tags [float] or [floating-point] and you'll see lots of other people asking the same question.

Comment: sorry for the duplicate Q I didn't know how to search for this, it didn't come up in the list when asking the Q.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Precision of Floating Point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872544/precision-of-floating-point)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

276/304 = 69/76 is a recurring "decimal" in both base 10 and base 2.

- decimal: 0.90(789473684210526315)
- binary: 0.11(101000011010111100)

So the result gets rounded off, and multiplying by the denominator may not result in the orginal numerator.  A more commonly-cited example of this situation is 1/3*3 = 0.33333333*3 = 0.99999999.

That the `double` version gives the exact answer is just a coincidence.  The rounding error in the multiplication just happens to cancel out the rounding error in the division.

If this result is confusing, it may be because you've heard that "`double` has rounding errors and `decimal` is exact".  But `decimal` is only exact at representing *decimal* fractions like 0.1 (which is 0.0 0011 0011... in binary).  When you have a factor of 19 in the denominator, it doesn't help you.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a clear explanation! So the solution is when comparing numeric values you should always round to the amount of decimals you're calculating with and you should be fine? In my case I need to verify if 275.999999999999999 == 276 so I'll just round up by 6 decimals and the result should be true.

Comment: @Peter No this doesn't work in every case either. For example imagine you're comparing 1.000000499 with 1.000000501 and round both to 6 decimals then you get 1.000000 != 1.000001 even so their difference is very small.

Comment: But the floating point rounding error in decimals could never be 1.000000499 right? It would always be the 27th decimal that's off?

Answer (score 4):

Well, floating point precision isn't 100%.
See for example: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate.htm

Comment: Also see this for Decimal vs Double: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/921a8ffc-9829-4145-bdc9-a96c1ec174a5/

Comment: @Filip Pretty much every post in that thread contains big mistakes.

Comment: so why is there a different result between the two? If both are floating point variables?

Comment: One is in base 10 and one in base 2. There are numbers you can exactly represent in base 10 and not base 2. For example `0.1` can be represented exactly in `Decimal` but not `Double`. And `Decimal` throws exceptions on overflows instead of silently using infinities or NaNs. But neither can represent `1/3` exactly.

Answer (score -2):

Well, mathematically 0.99999... == 1. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...
I know that programtically it poses some problems, but it's not totally a floating-point issue.

Comment: 0.9999999... == 1, but 0.99999999999999999999999 == 1-1e-23.