# Meaning of Precision Vs. Range of Double Types

Tags: double, ieee-754, floating

To begin with, allow me to confess that I'm an experienced programmer, who has over 10 years of programming experience. However, the question I'm asking here is the one, which has bugged me ever since, I first picked up a book on C about a decade back.

Below is an excerpt from a book on Python, explaining about Python Floating type.

> Floating-point numbers are represented using the native
>   double-precision (64-bit) representation of floating-point numbers on
>   the machine. Normally this is IEEE 754, which provides approximately
>   17 digits of precision and an exponent in the range of –308 to
>   308.This is the same as the double type in C.

What I never understood is the meaning of the phrase

> " ... which provides approximately 17 digits of precision and an
>   exponent in the range of –308 to 308 ... "

My intuition here goes astray, since i can understand the meaning of precision, but how can range be different from that. I mean, if a floating point number can represent a value up to 17 digits, (i.e. max of 1,000,000,000,000,000,00 - 1), then how can exponent be +308. wouldn't that make a 308 digit number if exponent is 10 or a rough 100 digit number if exponent is 2.

I hope, I'm able to express my confusion.

Regards
Vaid, Abhishek

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that we write 1500 with two digits of precision.  That means we are being precise enough to distinguish 1500 from 1600 and 1400, but not precise enough to distinguish 1500 from 1510 or 1490.  Telling those numbers apart would require three digits of precision.

Even though I wrote four digits, floating-point representation doesn't necessarily contain all these digits.  1500 is 1.5 * 10^3.  In decimal floating-point representation, with two digits of precision, only the first two digits of the number and the exponent would be stored, which I will write (1.5, 3).

Why is there a distinction between the "real" digits and the placeholder zeros?  Because it tells us how precisely we can represent numbers, that is, *what fraction of their value is lost due to approximation*.  We can distinguish 1500 = (1.5, 3) from 1500+100 = (1.6, 3).  But if we increase the exponent, we can't distinguish 15000 = (1.5, 4) from 15000+100 = (1.51, 4).  At best, we can approximate numbers within +/- 10% with two decimal digits of precision.  This is true no matter how small or large the exponent is allowed to be.

Answer (score 0):

The regular decimal representation of numbers obscures the issue. If instead, one considers them in normalised scientific notation to separate the mantissa and exponent, then the distinction is immediate. Normalisation is achieved by scaling the mantissa until it is between 0.0 and 1.0 and adjusting the exponent to avoid loss of scale.

The precision of the number is the number of digits in the mantissa. A floating point number has a limited number of bits to represent this portion of the value. It determines how accurately numbers that are similar in size can be distinguished.

The range determines the allowable values of the exponent. In your example, the range of -308 through 308 is represented independently of the mantissa value and is limited by the number of bits in the floating point number allocated to storing the range.

These two values can be varied independently to suit. For example, in many graphic pipelines much smaller values are represented with truncated values that are scaled to fit into even 16 bits.

Numerical methods libraries expend large amounts of effort in ensuring that these limits are not exceeded to maintain the correctness of calculations. Casual use will not usually encounter these limits.

The choices in IEEE 754 are accepted to be a reasonable trade off between precision and range. The 32-bit single has similar, but different limits. The question [What range of numbers can be represented in a 16-, 32- and 64-bit IEEE-754 systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872544/what-range-of-numbers-can-be-represented-in-a-16-32-and-64-bit-ieee-754-syste?rq=1) provides a longer summary and further links for more study.

Answer (score -3):

From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), Double Precision Floating Point numbers are expected to have a precision to 17 digits, or 17 SF. The exponent can be in the range -1022 to 1023.
 Their -308 to 308 would appear to be an error, or else an idea not fully explained.