# Scala. Strange result with floating point numbers

Tags: java, scala

Why do I get strange results when subtracting `2.99999...` from `3`?

```
scala> math.sqrt(3)
res0: Double = 1.7320508075688772

scala> math.pow(res0, 2)
res1: Double = 2.9999999999999996

scala> 3 - res1
res2: Double = 4.440892098500626E-16
```

Comment: looks ok to me. what's strange about it?

Comment: Note `...E-16` at the end. It is *very* tiny difference (a little more than 0000000000000000.1).

Comment: If you want uber precision you should consider using [apfloat](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/) (but even that gives no guarantee of a zero result)

Comment: How much precision to you want? To put things in perspective, to be accurate within E-16 is like specifying the distance of the sun from Pluto in mm and worrying about decimal places, hardly something to haggle over?

Comment: BTW this isn't unique to Scala. Go try this in any other programming language and you should get a similar result. This is a fundamental limitation of how your hardware does floating-point calculations.

Answer (score 7):

This is due to floating point precision; well documented in 
[What range of numbers can be represented in a 16-, 32- and 64-bit IEEE-754 systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872544/precision-of-floating-point)

Also, its worth noting here that there is no way the perfect computer could represent sqrt(3) in decimal as it's irrational!

Did you really think that sqrt(3) equals *exactly* 1.7320508075688772?

Comment: +1 for actually referencing floating-point limitations. Doubles are 64 bits. You're not going to be able to accurately represent an [irrational number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number) in any finite number of bits—period.

Answer (score 3):

This is exponential notation.  4 times 10^(-16) looks correct to me (within the limits of floating point accuracy).