# Why do I have different results by casting values

Tags: c++, casting

I'm really wasting a lot of time solving a problem in my code.
Now it is working, but I do not understand what is going wrong.

Using QT5 / gcc

```
int pos;
uint m_endZeit, m_startZeit;

float secPerPx = (pos * (m_endZeit - m_startZeit)) / static_cast<float>(width());
uint a = secPerPx + m_startZeit;
uint b = static_cast<uint>(secPerPx) + m_startZeit;
std::cout << a << " vs. " << b << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
1404809856 vs. 1404809893
```

Can anyone explain this to me? Why is this not the same?

Comment: Maybe because `(uint)(secPerPx + m_startZeit) != ((uint)secPerPx + m_startZeit)`?

Comment: Because floats does not gurantee absolute results. Float computation is always rounded to some bounds. You may read some wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: ah, thanks!!! now its clear. i will read the wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[What range of numbers can be represented in a 16-, 32- and 64-bit IEEE-754 systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872544/precision-of-floating-point)

The Precision of a float is roughly 8-9 digits and you already have 10.

```
uint a = secPerPx + m_startZeit;
```

The above code first casts m_startZeit to a float, adding the 2 values and then casts it back to an Integer.

```
uint b = static_cast<uint>(secPerPx) + m_startZeit;
```

This is casting the float to an integer BEFORE they both get added together.