# Error in sum of decimal values JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**Why not true result in JavaScript ?**

```
96.8 + 1.6 + 1.6 = 99.99999999;
```

---

```
96.8 + 3.2 = 100;
96.8 + (1.6 + 1.6) = 100;
```

Comment: Google "floating point imprecision".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872544/precision-of-floating-point