# C# collisions with Double.GetHashCode()

Tags: c#, hash, double

I need to generate a series of "defaults" for unknown object types with unique hash codes.  (Could be structs or a class with overridden GetHashCode such that it's default construction always returns the same hash.)

To handle most such cases, I use reflection to find numeric fields / properties that I can sequence.  So for example, if I can find a double field, I can just keep returning new objects with different values for that field that will generally change the hash.

So how to form that value sequence?  At first I thought I just needed to stick to the range of integer resolution and could just keep adding 1.0 each iteration.  Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872544/what-range-of-numbers-can-be-represented-in-a-16-32-and-64-bit-ieee-754-syste), I choose a range of -1E50 to 1E50.  But it turns out Double.GetHashCode returns the same hash for -1E50 and (-1E50 + 1.0).  Reducing the range way down to -1E15 to 1E15 seems to fix it, but I still don't know if what I'm doing is safe.  (I don't need anywhere near that big a range, but I do need to know I won't get collisions.)

So my question is, what range of double values can I use (incrementing by 1.0 or some other amount each time) to guarantee different hash results?  Does this answer change for float or other numeric types?

Comment: [FYI: Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) - You'll note that [`-1E50` and `-1E50 + 1` are the same value](https://rextester.com/SJZ57762).

Comment: If a class has int a; string s; data members - dont we do (in GetHashCode override) something like - return a.GetHashCode() ^ s.GetHashCode();   -- whats wrong with that?

Comment: @Prateek OP is missing the point that `-1E50` and `-1E50 + 1` become the same value.

Comment: No its not safe, doubles cant hold that sort of precision.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fCxNAp

Comment: You would be better off changing a *bit/s* strategically. however I feel this is all pointing back to a flawed design somewhere else

Comment: Note that you should use the value returned by `GetHashCode` for _potential equality_. Because you're pigeonholing bigger values, there's always going to be room for collisions. You need to check the actual value to confirm equality.

Answer (score 3):

Hash values are expected to collide, so trying to predict if some undocumented implementation of `GetHashCode` will have particular properties is a bad idea. If you need particular properties/guarantees from a hash function - implement one yourself (with built in types you'd likely have to wrap them to another struct first).

More specific to you case

- GetHashCode for `double` (or `float`) is generally not useful method as floating point calculations are imprecise and using value of expression to lookup in a dictionary indexed by floating point numbers pretty much guaranteed to fail all the time.
- the particular range you started from (1E50) does not have enough precision to represent valued differing by 1, indeed smaller range would be able to represent all integers - you can see from [MSDN-floating numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) that for double you get precision "15-17 digits". So yes -1E15 to 1E15 will have all integer values present with unique floating numbers.

If you want a "floating point" type that has reliable and guaranteed unique hash code for integer values you can have custom struct that returns rounded value as hash:

```
  struct MyDouble
  { 
      private double innerValue;
   
      // add implicit conversion to/from double

      public int override GetHashCode() { return (int)innerValue;}
      public bool oeverride Equal(object right) { return innerValue == (double)right;}
  }
```

Note: `equal` need to be implemented much better for real class, as well as all other comparisons need to be added.